# PHP/MySQL Auto Bidding System

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of writing a script for auto-bidding on an item. I think the easiest way to describe what I'm trying to do is to give you a scenario. Assuming $1,000 increments:

```
Asking Price: $1,000
Bidder 1: Max Bid of $4,000 -> High Bid: $1,000
Bidder 2: Max Bid of $3,000 -> High Bid: $3,000 -> [AUTO BIDDER 1] High Bid: $4,000
Bidder 3: Max Bid of $8,000 -> High Bid: $5,000
Bidder 4: Max Bid of $10,000 -> [AUTO BIDDER 3] High Bid: $8,000 -> High Bid: $9,000
```

I'm trying to come up with a loop to go through them, but I'm not exactly sure how. I have a loop I came up with that would work for every bid, but I'd like to to skip making each $1,000 increment, and instead jump up the highest bid based on the max bids.

I have two tables setup: *bids* and *maxbids*. This was the loop I thought of:

- Insert New Bid
- Start Loop

  - $high = get highest current bid from *bids* table
  - $next = get lowest maxbid where maxbid > $high from *maxbids*
  - if ($next >= ($high + increment)

    - Insert into *bids*
  - else // assume already have highest bid

    - break loop
- end loop

This would work, but as I said, this would keep inserting all $1,000 increments. I'd rather it work the way I showed above. Any suggestions?

Comment: please show any code you've already used in this process.

Comment: As I stated, I'm trying to come up with a loop. I haven't written anything yet, since it won't do what I'm looking for it to do. I could turn the loop I described into a MySQL query, but I don't know how that would be any more beneficial then what I provided. I'm not even looking for a code sample explicitly, maybe just a better "loop summary" like I provided.

Comment: thats not how S.O works

Comment: Could you try explaining your scenario a little better? I can't follow your diagram very well. The reason people are asking for code is because you marked this as PHP/MySQL, and this is more a question about designing an algorithm.

Comment: @Devin Have approached this with a condition tree rather than a loop. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Seems to me like you'd also want to take into account the ORDER in which bids were placed, i.e an earlier "*maxbid*"  would "win" over a later "*maxbid*" of the same amount. Maybe your algorithm is taking that into account?

Comment: @Dagon He's not asking for code, he's asking for guidance.

Comment: @Charlie Exactly. However, if somebody who answers wishes to include code, as Lightning Dust has done below, it's greatly appreciated. That's also why I included the PHP/MySQL part.

Comment: @Charlie, then hes in the wrong place

Comment: @Dagon I see questions even shorter than mine with no code in the original question either, and they get answered. I've asked questions on here before and never had an issue. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/about On the right: "Ask about... Software algorithms"

Comment: @Dagon No, he isn't. Control structures are just as much a part of programming, if not moreso, than syntax. He's showed a loop he's tried and he's asked for ways to improve it. What's the point in him writing code for that loop if he knows it's not the control structure he wants to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I think you can use a condition tree, rather than a loop

This is an interesting question, from how I understand it this function will trigger whenever a new bid is made. What you want to do should be something like:

1. Store the bid which the user is attempting to insert.
2. Get the high bid of the current bidder (there should be no bids higher than this, as they would have been resolved by a prior iteration of this function).

Next:

```
/**
 * $currentBidder = The current high bidder
 * $highBid       = The current high bidder's high bid
 * $thisBidder    = Bidder placing the new bid
 * $thisBid       = The bid that triggered the function
 * $increment     = The minimum bid increment
 */
function placeBid($currentBidder,$highBid,$thisBidder,$thisBid,$increment) {
    if($thisBid > $highBid) {
        // Insert $highBid as current bid, for $currentBidder
        if($thisBid > $highBid + $increment) {
            // Insert $thisBid into highbids table
            // Insert $highBid + $increment as current bid, for $thisBidder
        } else {
            // Insert $thisBid as current bid, for $thisBidder
        }
    } else {
        // Insert $thisBid as current bid for $thisBidder
        if($highBid > $thisBid + $increment) {
            // Insert $thisBid + $increment as current bid, for $currentBidder
        } else {
            // Insert $thisBid as current bid, for $currentBidder
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. In case the new bid is equal to the max bid, I have preferred on behalf of the current bidder over the newer bidder.
2. In all cases, I have preferred the highest bid, even when this wouldn't be higher than the current max bid + increment.

Obviously you'd have to check if it's the first bid and if so, set the bid to the minimum asking value. You'd have to check that the bid is valid (greater than current bid + increment. I haven't included that code.

From what I can see, if you trigger the function every time a bid is made, you won't need a loop at all, just a condition tree.

Scenario:

```
Item Current Bids: A, 4000
Item Current Max:  A, 4000
--> C bids 7500
Item Current Bids: A, 4000; C, 5000
Item Current Max:  C, 7500
--> B bids 7500
Item Current Bids: A, 4000; C, 5000; B, 7500; C, 7500
Item Current Max:  C, 7500
--> A bids 9000
Item Current Bids: A, 4000; C, 5000; B, 7000; C, 7500; A, 8500
Item Current Max:  A, 9000
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. I'm incorporating it in now and I'll post back with results. Looks very promising!

Comment: Finally finished the full script, and from what I have tested, it works perfect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Devin Glad to have helped. Enjoy.

Comment: Could you better document what params of placeBid method means? It seems, that does not work correctly in all cases to me. It looks like good, but not precisely.